# Запуск музыки по двойному клику мыши через приложение WPF в windows

Tags: wpf, windows, mediaplayer

Есть такой код. Хотел узнать, если поставить свое приложение WPF для запуска по умолчанию музыки, как передать Patch в Uri когда запускаешь трек в windows по двойному клику.

private void Open(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

```
        openFileDialog.Filter = "MP3 files (*.mp3)|*.mp3|All files (*.*)|*.*";

        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            mediaPlayer.Open(new Uri(openFileDialog.FileName));
            mediaPlayer.Play();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        bool success = false;
        for (int i = 0; i != e.Args.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (e.Args[i] == "/success")
            {
                success = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```